# spring cloud AWS detect if running local

Tags: spring-cloud

I'm looking for a quick, easy way for my Boot code to detect whether it is running on AWS or not (as opposed to local environment).

The only thing I could think of was to attempt to access some instance metadata, like @Value("${ami-id:N/A}") String ami;, then do an if check.  I could make this a @Conditional, but I was hoping something like this might be provided already by the framework (i.e. how the "cloud" profile is automatically active when running on Cloud Foundry)

Comment: The "cloud" profile is set automatically by the CF buildpack, so you won't get that on AWS. Not sure if there are any EC2 env vars that are automatically set.

Comment: Not sure if this could help in your case, but there is an annotation to conditionally define beans only when running on AWS: `org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.annotation.ConditionalOnAwsCloudEnvironment`

Comment: #Alain - that's the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Alain there are a couple of annotations [`@ConditionalOnAwsCloudEnvironment`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/context/annotation/ConditionalOnAwsCloudEnvironment.java) and [`@ConditionalOnMissingAwsCloudEnvironment`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/context/annotation/ConditionalOnMissingAwsCloudEnvironment.java) which you can use to annotate a class or method.  Under the hood these use [`AwsCloudEnvironmentCheckUtils#isRunningOnCloudEnvironment`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/context/support/env/AwsCloudEnvironmentCheckUtils.java) so you could do something like

```
final SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
if (AwsCloudEnvironmentCheckUtils.isRunningOnCloudEnvironment()) {
    app.setAdditionalProfiles("aws");
} else {
    app.setAdditionalProfiles("local");
}
    app.run(args);
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, those didn't exist when I wrote the original question - k

Comment: If you do not want the method to log exception when the call to the metadata service fails, use this property in application properties: logging.level.com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils=error